Exchange Online - permission to Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics
What permissions does Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics for PowerShell Exchange Online Module require?
Connect-ExchangeOnline

Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -Identity "mail@domain.com" -Folderscope "Inbox"

From the Global Admin level, I obtain information about statistics for folders:
ame                              : Skrzynka odbiorcza
SearchFolder                      : False
CreationTime                      : 30/06/2023 13:40:11
LastModifiedTime                  : 14/05/2024 11:38:31
FolderPath                        : /Skrzynka odbiorcza
FolderId                          : LgAAAABbZ7sblLQ1RK2Ec3cRt7fiAQAdLsqdNxl6Sao/wDmuiS89AAAAAAEMAAAB
ContentFolder                     : True
ContentMailboxGuid                : 09d5k235-bd72-4938-g504-cac77879bmd9
Identity                          : mail@domain.com\Skrzynka odbiorcza
FolderType                        : Inbox
RawContentMailboxGuid             : 09d5k235-bd72-4938-g504-cac77879bmd9
Movable                           : False
RecoverableItemsFolder            : False
AssociatedIPMFolderPath           : 
ContainerClass                    : 
Flags                             : 
TargetQuota                       : User
StorageQuota                      : Unlimited
StorageWarningQuota               : Unlimited
VisibleItemsInFolder              : 0
HiddenItemsInFolder               : 17
ItemsInFolder                     : 17
DeletedItemsInFolder              : 0
FolderSize                        : 923.6 KB (945,758 bytes)
ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders        : 15
DeletedItemsInFolderAndSubfolders : 0
FolderAndSubfolderSize            : 923.6 KB (945,758 bytes)
CurrentSchemaVersion              : 1.122
OldestItemReceivedDate            : 
NewestItemReceivedDate            : 
OldestDeletedItemReceivedDate     : 
NewestDeletedItemReceivedDate     : 
OldestItemLastModifiedDate        : 
NewestItemLastModifiedDate        : 
OldestDeletedItemLastModifiedDate : 
NewestDeletedItemLastModifiedDate : 
ManagedFolder                     : 
DeletePolicy                      : 
ArchivePolicy                     : 
TopSubject                        : 
TopSubjectSize                    : 0 B (0 bytes)
TopSubjectCount                   : 0
TopSubjectClass                   : 
TopSubjectPath                    : 
TopSubjectReceivedTime            : 
TopSubjectFrom                    : 
TopClientInfoForSubject           : 
TopClientInfoCountForSubject      : 0
SearchFolders                     : {}
AuditAuxMailboxGuid               : 
AuditFolderStubSize               : 
LastMovedTimeStamp                : 
LowLatencyContainerId             : 
LowLatencyContainerFlags          : 
LowLatencyContainerQuota          : Unlimited
Diagnostics                       : 
DiagnosticInfo                    : 
ChangedProperties                 : {}

But from user mail@domain.com i'm only get this error:
Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics: An error occurred while processing this request.. {"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"User is not allowed to call Get-MailboxFolderStatistics","innererror":{"message":"User is not allowed to call Get-MailboxFolderStatistics","type":"Microsoft.Exchange.Admin.OData.Core.ODataServiceException","stacktrace":""}}}. An error was read from the payload. See the 'Error' property for more details.. 

Im try to add permision to mail@domain.com user

Solution is:

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "mail@domain.com" -User "mail@domain.com" -AccessRights Reviewer

to set as Global admin, now mail@domain.com get FolderStatistics
